# Why adding TimeConstrained to Integrate causes TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

in Version 13.2.1, calling `Integrate` works on this integral, and gives result almost immediately in few seconds (result is wrong, it says zero, but that is besides the point).

When adding `TimeConstrained`, now an error is generated and session terminates.

[image]

Compare to version 13.1, where adding `TimeConstrained` causes no such error.

[image]

The question is: Why adding `TimeConstrained` gives error and not same result without? And is there a workaround?

Notice that 13.1 result is not zero for same integral.

13.2.1 on windows 10.

### Code

```
ClearAll[x]
integrand = (4335 + 
     289*x + (-289*x + 5*x^2)*Log[(-289 + 5*x)/x]*
      Log[Log[(-289 + 5*x)/x]])/((-289*x + 5*x^2)*Log[(-289 + 5*x)/x]);
Integrate[integrand, x]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[integrand, x], 60*3]
```

### More examples found

All examples below show the same exact problem as the above. So will only give the integrands to save space.

```
integrand = (((-3)*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 15*x + (-30))*
     Log[((-4)*x^2 + 20)/(x^2)] + ((-30)*x + (-60)))/((4*x^5 + 
      24*x^4 + 28*x^3 + (-88)*x^2 + (-240)*x + (-160))*
    Log[((-4)*x^2 + 20)/(x^2)]^2)

integrand = ((3*x + (-6))*Log[(((-1)*x + 2)*Exp[1])/x] + 
    2*x)/((x^3 + (-2)*x^2)*Log[(((-1)*x + 2)*Exp[1])/x])

integrand = (3*Exp[Log[4]^8]*
     Log[Log[2]] + (3*Exp[Log[4]^8]*Log[x] + ((-8)*x + (-3))*
       Exp[Log[4]^8]*Log[(8*x + 3)/x]))/((8*x^2 + 3*x)*
     Log[(8*x + 3)/x]^2*Log[Log[2]]^2 + (16*x^2 + 6*x)*
     Log[(8*x + 3)/x]^2*Log[x]*Log[Log[2]] + (8*x^2 + 3*x)*
     Log[(8*x + 3)/x]^2*Log[x]^2)

integrand = (((-48)*x^5 + 16*x^4 + 225*x + (-75))*
     Log[((-3)*x + 1)/x] + (16*x^4 + (-64)*x^3 + 
      25))/((48*x^5 + (-16)*x^4)*Log[((-3)*x + 1)/x]^2)

integrand = ((8*x + 4)*Log[(4*x + 2)/x] + 
    x)/((2*x^3 + x^2)*Log[(4*x + 2)/x]*
     Log[Log[(4*x + 2)/x]]^2 + (16*x^2 + 8*x)*Log[(4*x + 2)/x]*
     Log[Log[(4*x + 2)/x]] + (32*x + 16)*Log[(4*x + 2)/x])

integrand=((4*x^3+8*x^2+(-4)*x+(-8))*Log[(x+1)/x]^2+x)/((x^3+x^2)*Log[(x+1)/x]^2)

integrand = ((5*x*Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1] + (-25)*x)*Exp[5*Log[2*x + 2]]*
     Log[(-1)*Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1] + 5]*
     Log[Log[(-1)*Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1] + 5]] + (((-1)*x + (-1))*
       Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1]*Exp[5*Log[2*x + 2]] + (x + 1)*Exp[16]*
       Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1]))/(((x^2 + x)*
       Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1] + ((-5)*x^2 + (-5)*x))*
    Log[(-1)*Exp[(-1)*Log[x] + 1] + 5])

integrand = ((10*x + (-10))*Log[(x + (-1))/(2*x)]*
     Log[x] + ((10*x^3 + (-10)*x^2)*
       Log[(x + (-1))/(2*x)] + (-5)))/((x^2 + (-1)*x)*
    Log[(x + (-1))/(2*x)])

integrand = (((-3)*x^2 + 6*x + (-3))*Exp[x]*Log[((-1)*x + 1)/x] + 
    3*Exp[x])/((x^3 + (-1)*x^2)*Exp[1]*Log[((-1)*x + 1)/x]^2)
```

---

The following examples are different from all the above, in that `Integrate[integrand, x]` does not give zero, but adding `TimeConstrained` still gives `TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]`

[image]

**Code**

```
integrand = (((x + 13)*Log[5] + (x^3 + 13*x^2 + x + 13))*
     Log[(3*x + 39)/x]^2 + (x^3 + 13*x^2)*Log[(3*x + 39)/x] + 
    13*x^2)/((x^3 + 13*x^2)*Log[(3*x + 39)/x]^2)
Integrate[integrand, x]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[integrand, x], 60]
```

[image]

**Code**

```
integrand = ((2*x^4*Exp[2] + 2*x^5)*
     Log[(12*Exp[2] + 12*x)/x]^4 + (-4)*x^4*Exp[2]*
     Log[(12*Exp[2] + 12*x)/x]^3 + (2*x^3*Exp[2] + 2*x^4)*
     Log[(12*Exp[2] + 12*x)/x]^2 + (4*x^2*Exp[2]*Log[3] + (-4)*x^3*
        Exp[2])*Log[(12*Exp[2] + 12*x)/x] + (((-2)*Exp[2] + (-2)*x)*
       Log[3]^2 + (2*x*Exp[2] + 2*x^2)*Log[3]))/(x^3*Exp[2] + x^4)
Integrate[integrand, x]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[integrand, x], 60]
```

ps. in case this is a new bug, I also just send email to Wolfram support.
**Case ID [CASE:5023223]**

Comment: Perhaps not  in order of importance, but (1) Regarding "[R]result is wrong, it says zero, but that is besides the point" I would say instead that this is a separate bug (or bugs), also quite important, but outside the scope of this question. (2) Regarding "When adding TimeConstrained, now an error is generated and session terminates", this is not actually what a terminated evaluation does. A session ending is generally taken to mean either kernel or all of Mathematica has crashed. More to come.

Comment: (3) Offhand I do not know what was the cause of these issues, but it appears that all of them are fixed for version 13.3. (4) Those last two examples, while not returning 0, are giving results that are not correct. The first has been corrected in 13.3. The second returns unevaluated in 13.3. So this does seem like progress. (5) I suspect the 0 results were a bad side-effect of some fixes to indefinite integration. Not sure why the terminated evaluations have appeared.

Comment: And (6)  I apologize for these problems having appeared in 13.2. It's a lesson in humility I guess. (for me, not you or other users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

integrand = (4335 + 289*x + (-289*x + 5*x^2)*
      Log[(-289 + 5*x)/x]*
      Log[Log[(-289 + 5*x)/x]])/
   ((-289*x + 5*x^2)*Log[(-289 + 5*x)/x]);
```

The `TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit]` arises without specifying a time constraint using other approaches.

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[integrand, x]]

(* TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] *)

Assuming[x < 0, Integrate[integrand, x]]

(* TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] *)

Assuming[x != 0, Integrate[integrand, x]]

(* TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] *)

Integrate[#, x] & /@ Simplify[integrand]

(* 289 ∫(15 + x)/(x (-289 + 5 x) Log[5 - 289/x]) \[DifferentialD]x + 
 TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] *)

Integrate[#, x] & /@ Expand[integrand]

(* -289 ∫(
    x Log[Log[(-289 + 5 x)/x]])/(-289 x + 5 x^2) \[DifferentialD]x + 
 5 ∫(
    x^2 Log[Log[(-289 + 5 x)/x]])/(-289 x + 5 x^2) \[DifferentialD]x + 
 2 TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] *)

Integrate[#, x] & /@ (Simplify /@ Expand[integrand])

(* -289 ∫Log[Log[5 - 289/x]]/(-289 + 5 x) \[DifferentialD]x + 
 5 ∫(x Log[Log[5 - 289/x]])/(-289 + 5 x) \[DifferentialD]x + 
 2 TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] *)
```